# iOS Google Cloud Messaging invalid payload

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, push

I've managed to get GCM work on iOS, but I still can't send a proper payload, so the push would appear on the lock screen.

If I send

```
{
  "to" : "my google token",
  "notification" : {
     "title" : "Hello, world!",
     "body" : "default",
     "badge":5
  }
}
```

The device just doesn't receive the push. But if I remove "notification" object - push goes flawlessly. Any thoughts?

Reviewed response - I see

```
{
 "multicast_id":8119244679462523689,
 "success":0,
 "failure":1,
 "canonical_ids":0,
 "results":[{
             "error":"InternalServerError"
           }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. I've used production certificate, but on initialisation of the GCM SDK I had sandbox mode ON.

```
  [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];
 _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                       kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
```

Changed to OFF and everything worked fine.